# Make a div full screen like a background

Tags: html, css, css-position, fullscreen

I have the following:
http://jsfiddle.net/B6dFk/embedded/result/

Excerpts:

HTML:

```
<div id="aboutback">
    This is a background
</div>
<div id="workback">
    This is another background
</div>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="innerwrapper">

 <div id="nav">
  <div id="about" class="menu1">
   <p>About</p>
  </div>

<div id="aboutsub">
  <div id="team" class="menu2">
   <p>Team</p>
  </div>
  <div id="experience" class="menu2">
   <p>Experience</p>
  </div>
  <div id="difference" class="menu2">
   <p>Difference</p>
  </div>
</div>

  <div id="work" class="menu1">
   <p>Work</p>
  </div>

<div id="worksub">
  <div id="services" class="menu2">
   <p>Services</p>
  </div>
  <div id="ourprocess" class="menu2">
   <p>Our Process</p>
  </div>
</div>

  <div id="portfolio" class="menu1">
   <p>Portfolio</p>
  </div>
  <div id="contact" class="menu1">
   <p>Contact</p>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div id="outerviewer">
  <div id="innerviewer">

<p>
Filler
</p>

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#aboutback
{
    position: absolute;
    background: #11ac92;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

I want the `#aboutback` and the `#workback` to take up the full background at all times.  These will have images in them which i will animate using jquery.

The problem is, when the window isn't full page(so the scrollbar appears) and you scroll down, you see the white nothingness of despair.

It's worth noting I have tried setting the position of the `body` tag which alters the effect but does not fix it.  For example, `position:absolute;` will push everything left and leave a white space on the right.

Any simple solutions, please?

Comment: Try googling "full bleed background"?

Comment: Ah, I was making the div position:absolute; and I needed to make it fixed!

Answer (score 0):

```
 body{
   height:100%;
   overflow:hidden;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html{height:100%;}
```

`body{height:100%;}`

     `divclass{height:100%;}`

Comment: outer elements must have  100% height

Comment: The inner most structural div might need to be min-height 100 to stretch out the html and body as well.